# Cannot connect to sql server from virtualized environment

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, virtualization, firewall, hyper-v

I have a windows server 2012 R1 Enterprise  that my colleague set up in a virtualized environment, the host PC is no not domain joined, but the virtual environment is.

The issue is for some reason that server is not able to connect to SQL servers within the domain network. I've enabled IP/firewall and I can connect to the SQL server from all the other non-virtual machines, so, I don't think it's to do anything with the SQL

It's just that hyper-v environment that I'm having issues with. I cannot even connect using the excel, it simply says "SQL Server does not exist or access denied." Anyone else experienced the same issue?

here is the error message I get trying to connect to one of SQL servers.

```
 "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is corrrect and that SQL server is configured to allow remote connection. (Provider: Named Pipes Provider, Error: 40-Could not open a connection to SQL server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:5) --> Access is denied
```

thanks

Comment: when you say "can't connect" could you add which error messages that you may be seeing?

Comment: thanks for the reply, I've added the error message."A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is corrrect and that SQL server is configured to allow remote connection. (Provider: Named Pipes Provider, Error: 40-Could not open a connection to SQL server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:5) --> Access is denied"

Comment: Does your sql server service started?

Comment: Yes, the service is on, and is proofed by the fact that I can connect to it from other non-virtual PCs

Comment: you can specify the type and order of priority for the type of transport to use in this case the connection is attempting to use "named pipes" which looks like its not enabled on the server that you are trying to connect to. This can be configured for the sql instance for both the transports enabled and the priority in which to use them, if TCP is used for example move named pipes down in priority or disable it.

Comment: How is the virtualized SQL server attempting to connect to other SQL servers?

Comment: @mike I've tried both IP as well as FQN, but just typing in one of those in the servername....

Comment: has to do with how the server is configured and the sql server configuration utility is used to change transports and priorities. Secondly you can connect from non-virtual to virtual but how are you connecting virtual sql server to others (linked tables or something else)?

Comment: @mike, I'm not sure about your first comment, anyway to find out? to the second point, all I'm doing is opening SQL Server Management Studio and typing the server's FQN

Comment: when connecting to the database server click on the connection properties tab and you will see a network protocol dropdown, try selecting TCP/IP and then connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the order and types of protocols used to connect to sql server are configured when sql server is installed. the order and priority of which can be used to influence the default connection protocol when using SQL server management studio The error

> (Provider: Named Pipes Provider, Error: 40-Could not open a connection to SQL server) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:5) --> Access is denied"

Indicates that the protocol on the SQL server that the SQL server management studio is requested is either

1. Blocked by the firewall on the inbound or outbound machine
2. Or the protocol is not enabled

The connection protocol default can be overridden by selecting the connection properties tab and selecting another protocol choice other than default.

to see what default is configured for (on the server that sql studio is installed on" run the following query against the master database

```
SELECT net_transport 
  FROM sys.dm_exec_connections 
       WHERE session_id = @@SPID;
```

Comment: the above sql assumes that you can connect to the master database on the same system that sql server is installed on (and the correct instance as well)

Comment: I changed the network protocol to TCP/IP, and typed the specific IP address of the destination SQL, but it returned another error: "An Attempt was made to access a sockate in a way forbidden by its access permissions"

Comment: I can however, connect to the same server, using TCP/IP protocol from other non-virtualized PC.

Comment: when I run    SELECT net_transport, it returns "TCP" as result

Comment: starts to look like an outbound firewall issue on the virtualized PC

Comment: Feel extremely dumb... Thank you so much, for some reason I had it blocked in the outbound firewall...

Comment: I'm getting this same error but just with Shared memory????